# Add-migration does not work, database out of sync

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I've managed somehow to get my databases out of sync. I'm using the code-first approach in building this `MVC 4` C#.

```
public class RandomTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public bool? Verified { get; set; }
}
```

In adding a new table into an existing model I've tried using `add-migration RandomTable` and then update-database.

However I've noticed the migration is empty so I believe it is out of sync completely.

How do I recover this?

Comment: If your migration is empty, then everything is working as it should and there's nothing to migrate. If you'd got "out of sync" `add-migration` would give you an error message. Are you sure you added a `DbSet<RandomTable>` to your data context class?

Comment: Yes the DbSet<RandomTable> is in the context class. However the table does not add.

Comment: No errors, either when you `add-migration`, `update-database` or run your project?

Comment: Nothing, if there was an error I'd know where to start.

Comment: Maybe you have automatic migrations turned on, and so the migration is empty because the table already exists?

Comment: The table does not exist, that is the weird part.

Comment: What does your db configuration look like? Could you please post it by editing the question..

Comment: Use -ConnectionString and -ConnectionProviderName to sure the correct db is in use.

Comment: So Masoud's little gem has got me back on track. I was trying to update the wrong DB. Using the connection string seems to have updated the DB.